# Disable CategoryTree Sidebar for anonymous users

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am using the CategoryTree extension for MediaWiki. I want to hide the Sidebar in case the visitor is anonymous.

```
wgUseAjax = true;
require_once( "$IP/extensions/CategoryTree/CategoryTree.php" );
$wgCategoryTreeSidebarRoot = "SomeCategory";
$wgCategoryTreeSidebarOptions = array();
$wgCategoryTreeSidebarOptions['mode'] = CT_MODE_ALL;
```

(Extension: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree))

I found an extension called HideSidebar.

the code looks like this

```
function efHideSidebar($skin, &$bar) {
        global $wgUser;
        // Hide sidebar for anonymous users
        if (!$wgUser->isLoggedIn()) {
                $url = Title::makeTitle(NS_SPECIAL, 'UserLogin')->getLocalUrl();
                $bar = array(
                        'navigation' => array(
                                array('text'   => 'Login',
                                      'href'   => $url,
                                      'id'     => 'n-login',
                                      'active' => '')
                        )
                );
        }
        return true;
}
```

But this code does only hide the navigation and toolbox and not the category tree sidebar.

Is there an easy way with another hook to somehow deactivate the CategoryTree Extension when the visitor is anonymous?

This code is working for the sidebar not for the category widget. Actually the function is injected with a hook: $wgHooks['SkinBuildSidebar'][] = 'efHideSidebar'; 
You will find the full code here. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HideSidebar

How to make something similar for the CategoryTreeSidebar?

Comment: The sidebar is heavily cached, altering its content in PHP based on the user's characteristics is very liable to failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes 9 years late, but surprisingly nothing has changed and the issue is still there.

**TL;DR**
go to `/extensions/HideSidebar/extension.json`

And replace `SkinBuildSideBar` for `SidebarBeforeOutput` at line 16.

**TS;WM**

I had the same error and looking a bit I've been able to find that if you modify which Hook does the HideSidebar hook to, you are able to actually modify the overall input.

The issue resides in the fact that the sidebar is built and then categorytree adds on top. If you hook into the end of build function (`SkinBuildSidebar`) as the original HideSidebar does, categorytree is not there yet and therefore still gets added.

If you modify the extension to be hooked to `SidebarBeforeOutput` then it works perfectly, including the Categorytree.

Comment: I trust you that it works and going to accept the answer. I didn't do anything with MediaWiki since years.